# How to pass argument in "next" middleware in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Nodejs/Express Js, Right now i am working on "middleware function", following is example of middleware function,Here is my current code

```
const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers.authorization === 'secret-token') {
    next(); // Proceed to the next middleware or route handler
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }
};

// Using the middleware function for a specific route
app.get('/api/protected', authMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  res.send('Protected route');
});
```

1. if we not pass "argument" inside "next" middleware function then by default go to next function ? ('api/protected")
2. If we want to pass argument inside "next" middleware then how can we do this ?